# Linear Regression Coeficients in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to make a linear regression with a csv and I need to obtain the coefficients but I don't know how. This is what I have tried:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = datos1['Ozone']
y = datos1['Temp']
x = np.array(x)
y= np.array(y)
model = sm.OLS(y, x)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: The coefficients are in the results.summary() object and should be printed out. You can use help() on the object to see how to access the values.

Comment: will you post the ozone and temp data?  it helps to see if ozone is statistically significant to temperature

Answer (score 0):

Try running,

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = datos1['Ozone']
y = datos1['Temp']
x = np.array(x)`enter code here`
y= np.array(y)
model = sm.OLS(y, x)
results = model.fit()

print(results.params)
```

For details please see: [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the parameters of the OLS model.

### Way 1: Use `model.params`

```
x = datos1['Ozone']
y = datos1['Temp']
x = np.array(x)
y= np.array(y)
model = sm.OLS(y, x)
results = model.fit()
print(results.params)
```

### Way 2: Use `model.summary()` with pandas

```
x = datos1['Ozone']
y = datos1['Temp']
x = np.array(x)
y= np.array(y)
model = sm.OLS(y, x)
results = model.fit()

df = pd.read_html(results.summary().tables[1].as_html(),header=0,index_col=0)[0]
print(df.columns.values) # get parameters as dataframe 
print(df['coef']) # get coefficients
```